# Unifying view bounds within classes

Tags: scala, typeclass

I've been fighting to find a way to handle the following case where I would like to find a common view (or super class) that unifies the type parameters such that I can access a type class that compares apples to apples:

```
case class Foo[A](i:A) {
  def cmp[B:Ordering, C <% B](b:B)(implicit ev: A => B) = implicitly[Ordering[B]].lt(i,b)
}
// Foo(1).cmp(2.0) works
// Foo(1.0).cmp(2) complains about evidence of Double => Int
```

Now, this can trivially be done with a simple function:

```
def cmp[A:Ordering](a1:A, a2:A) = implicitly[Ordering[A]].lt(a1,a2)
// cmp(Foo(1).a, 1.0)
// cmp(Foo(1.0).a, 1)
```

However, I want it to live as a method of Foo.  Any ideas on what I can do to coerce it to use the view bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rely on a type class. A bit heavy, but works:

```
trait Cmp[A,B] {
  def cmp( a: A, b: B ): Boolean
}
trait LowPriorityCmpImplicits {
  implicit def cmp1[A,B]( implicit conv: A => B, ord: Ordering[B] ) = new Cmp[A, B]{ 
    def cmp( a: A, b: B ) = ord.lt(conv(a), b) 
  }
}
object Cmp extends LowPriorityCmpImplicits {
  implicit def cmp2[A,B]( implicit conv: B => A, ord: Ordering[A] ) = new Cmp[A, B]{ 
    def cmp( a: A, b: B ) = ord.lt(a, conv(b)) 
  }
}

case class Foo[A](i:A) {
  def cmp[B](b: B)(implicit cmp: Cmp[A,B]) = cmp.cmp( i, b )
}
```

The `LowPriorityCmpImplicits` trait is to avoid ambiguity when both types are the same (`cmp2` will be favored over `cmp1`)
Test:

```
scala> Foo(1).cmp(2.0)
res0: Boolean = true
scala> Foo(1.0).cmp(2)
res1: Boolean = true
scala> Foo(1).cmp(2)
res2: Boolean = true
scala> Foo(2).cmp(1.0)
res3: Boolean = false
scala> Foo(2.0).cmp(1)
res4: Boolean = false
scala> Foo(2).cmp(1)
res5: Boolean = false
```

Comment: This is a very reasonably work around which solves my problem.  Any thoughts on why the compiler has troubles with this form of problem?  It's unfortunately rather common when trying to handle both numerics and regular classes.